# Teamcity and git repository, connection fails

Tags: git, teamcity, appharbor

I am getting this error when doing a test connection against my git repository (located on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/)) from TeamCity 6.5. Can anybody explain this error more closely?

> invalid advertisement of 001E# service=git-upload-pack

Comment: Did you look in the server logs ?

Comment: The teamcity logs had nothing extra on this error. Just repeating the same error message

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely caused by a bad interaction between the TeamCity JGit-based client and AppHabor's WebGitNet-based Git-implementation. The same symptoms are mentioned [here](https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet/issues/24). I'm going to try and see if we can back-port that patch.

*Edit:* As rarouš mentions, using the [Github integration](http://blog.appharbor.com/2011/10/13/announcing-github-support) (or a git repository at Bitbucket) is also a really good option.

Comment: Thx a lot. Just let me know if you manage to patch it up and I will test the connection again. Loving Appharbor btw. It is a fantastic service.

Comment: You can use GitHub instead (witch works with TeamCity) for your repository a connect it with your AppHarbor for deployment. This is new feature https://github.com/blog/961-deploy-to-appharbor-from-github

Answer (score 1):

I checked network interaction with Wireshark and I found that JGit which TeamCity uses treats this packet as incorrect:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2012 09:56:30 GMT
Content-Length: 255

001d# service=git-upload-pack ... <other stuff>
```

Precisely it is confused by `charset=utf-8` part (which was added when call to `response.Write(string)` is performed). msysgit handles such packet correctly, though.

[This](https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet/issues/24) fixes the issue by replacing `Write(string)` with binary write. Other option is to specify `response.Charset = null;` explicitly.

I tested info on [GitWebAccess](http://gitweb.codeplex.com/) which has similar problems and made pull request with fix [here](https://github.com/yysun/Git-Web-Access/pull/4).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when trying to checkout a project from Eclipse with EGit. In my case I simply gave the wrong project path. If you come here because you got this error -> check your repository path first